# Convert an array of objects into different format based on one property

Tags: javascript

Below is my array of objects

```
[
{ field: 'EXPECTEDDATE', operator: 'gte', value: '20200601' },
{ field: 'EXPECTEDDATE', operator: 'lte', value: '20200630' },
{ field: 'PYNAME', operator: 'contains', value: 'abc' },
{ field: 'DEPT', operator: 'eq', value: 'IT' }
]
```

I want to change the format of it to pass it to an API like below

```
{
attibuteName: 'PYNAME',
filterOperator1: 'contains',
filterValue1: 'abc',
filterOperator2: '',
filterValue2: '',
},
{
attibuteName: 'DEPT',
filterOperator1: 'eq',
filterValue1: 'IT',
filterOperator2: '',
filterValue2: '',
},
 {
attibuteName: 'EXPECTEDDATE',
filterOperator1: 'gte',
filterValue1: '20200601',
filterOperator2: 'lte',
filterValue2: '20200630',
}
```

Below is my current code and I am stuck at merging the filterOperator2 and filterValue2 to same object for the same field in forEach loop.

```
filtersArray.forEach((element, index, array) => {
   filterObject = gridColumns.find(currField => currField.attributeName === element.field);
   const filop1 = 'filterOperator1';
   const filval1 = 'filterValue1';
   const filop2 = 'filterOperator2';
   const filval2 = 'filterValue2';
   filterObject[filop1] = element.operator;      
   filterObject[filval1] = element.value;
   columnList.push(filterObject);
});
return columnList;
}
```

Please suggest how can I do this. Thanks.

Comment: is destructuring possible here in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `.reduce()`. This solution is pretty hardcoded and not very dynamic

```js
let arr = [
{ field: 'EXPECTEDDATE', operator: 'gte', value: '20200601' },
{ field: 'EXPECTEDDATE', operator: 'lte', value: '20200630' },
{ field: 'PYNAME', operator: 'contains', value: 'abc' },
{ field: 'DEPT', operator: 'eq', value: 'IT' }
]

let result = arr.reduce((a,v) => {
   let index = a.findIndex(el => el.attibuteName === v.field);
   if(index !== -1){
      a[index].filterOperator2 = v.operator;
      a[index].filterValue2 = v.value;
      return a;
   }
   a.push({
      attibuteName: v.field,
      filterOperator1: v.operator,
      filterValue1: v.value,
      filterOperator2: "",
      filterValue2: ""
   })
   return a;
},[])

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this:

```js
var arr= [
{ field: 'EXPECTEDDATE', operator: 'gte', value: '20200601' },
{ field: 'EXPECTEDDATE', operator: 'lte', value: '20200630' },
{ field: 'PYNAME', operator: 'contains', value: 'abc' },
{ field: 'DEPT', operator: 'eq', value: 'IT' }
]

var res = arr.reduce((acc, {field, operator, value})=>{
  if(acc[field]){
    if(!acc[field].filterValue2){
      acc[field].filterValue2= value
    }
    if(!acc[field].filterOperator2){
      acc[field].filterOperator2= operator
    }
 }else{
  acc[field] =  {
    attibuteName: field,
    filterOperator1:operator,
    filterValue1: value,
    filterOperator2: '',
    filterValue2: '',
  };

 }
return acc
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(res))
```

Comment: But using this approach, how can I get the remaining properties coming from 'filterObject'?

Comment: I'm just destructuring all the properties and using them. You can destructure any other property just like this.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#:~:text=The%20destructuring%20assignment%20syntax%20is,from%20objects%2C%20into%20distinct%20variables.